# How to change the color of multiple object at once?

Tags: color

I tried to select a few cubes, then select a color but only the color of the active one is changed.

[image]

How to change the color of all selected objects at once?

I'm using Blender 3.2.0 on macos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer is not quite accurate.
You do not have to have the same material on each object. You can have a completely new material for every object. You simply have to select a material from the dropdown list or select "new" if there are none available and then adjust the look in the shader editor.

If you want multiple objects to share the same material then you simply have to select each object and assign the same material to them. If there are many objects then the best way is to select all the objects making sure the object with the desired material is active (the last one selected) then type, "CTRL L" and select link materials from the list. This will assign the material from the active object to all the other objects and they will all share the same material which can be updated at any time in the shader editor.

Answer (score 2):

If you're attempting to set the same color for all of them you would first need to assign the same material to all of them then change the color of the material.

**You need to select this dropdown and make sure it is the same for each object**

[image]

---

If you want different colors on each cube you would need to make a shader setup in the shading tab that resembles something like the image below. **Though all the objects still need to have the same material**

*Add an Object Info Node, Plug random Into a ColorRamp set to constant and change the colors of the markers to pick which colors you want*

[image]